# Owl carousel is not identified in AngularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs, owl-carousel

```
<div>
   <div class="col-12 row mx-0 justify-content-center align-items-center border h-70 text-secondary">
      <span>
         <ul>
            <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
               <li ng-repeat="result in result.results" style="display: inline; white-space: nowrap; list-style-type: none; padding-right: 20px;">
                  <img class="scroll" ng-src="{{result.images}}" alt="Avatar"> 
               </li>
         </ul>
         </div>
      </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to display the images using `ng-repeat` in the continuous scroll.  I am using the Owl carousel but it is not showing the images and not working.  I have loaded all the CDNs.

If I remove the `class="owl-carousel owl-theme"` it is showing the images normally in a line.

Comment: Your `<div>` tag should be before the `<ul>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Please just place like

```
<img class="scroll" ng-src="{{result}}" alt="Avatar">
```

and check with this

Comment: it is just returning the images vertically

Comment: Please check your css